# Node serving blank page

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I have an index.html page which is present at:

D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete\step1\index.html

I am trying to execute D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete\step1\server.js file via node:

"C:\Program Files\nodejs>node.exe D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete\step1\server.js"

Server.js code:

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new (static.Server)("D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete\step1");
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(2011);
```

When I go to hit:
http://localhost:2011/
I see empty page. Any idea why?

The console shows "http://localhost:2011/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep `file.serve(req,res)` within `req.addListener()`

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new (static.Server)("./");
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

req.addListener('end',function(){   //   <--
  file.serve(req, res);
}).resume()                         //   <-- 

}).listen(2011);
```

Also, you have a  couple of other options to go with(if you dont want to stick with `node-static`)

**Option-1:** Use `fs` module to read the file and send it on request

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');    
fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(2011);
});
```

**Option-2:**
Use a web app framework like `express()`. It provides several great features to simplify the power of node. Then you can either define a specific route for '/' to send your `index.html`

```
var express= require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('index.html',{ root:__dirname })
})

app.listen(2011)
```

or serve your static assets straightaway:

```
var express= require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //this will make index.html available to every request

app.listen(2011)
```

`__dirname` is the directory that the currently executing script is in. Since both `server.js` and `index.html` are at same level, `__dirname` will point to *D:\GITProjects\codelab\complete\step1*

Comment: Do I need to write this at the end of Server.js code

Comment: @raj: Apologies, I assumed you were using express(). Updated the answer with fix for your code and other available options